# Observing Firebase nodes before they exist

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observers

Lets say I want current user to observe when theres a `childAdded` to the `friendRequest` node so they can see if they are the recipient. If there are zero friend requests, when observer is called from client, will observer still be listening when a friend request comes through at a later time? If not, does this mean I need to have some arbitrary placeholder value to assure the node exists, when client attempts to observe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can most definitely observe/listen to a location that has no data.  Your observer/listener will still be called when data arrives there.

This is behavior you can pretty easily test for yourself by writing the observer code in your app, and making a quick change in the Firebase Realtime Database console that would trigger your observer.